# Tabbed Description - Tab 3&4 Not working

Tags: javascript, html, shopify

Ok I tried to figure it out but couldn't, I have a tabbed description box and the first two tabs are working, but when I add the information to tabs 3&4 they don't work. They only seem to work if I just have a total of two tabs working at a time, so I can have 1+3 or 1+4 or 2+4 etc

Could really use your help.

```
{{ product.description }}<div id="tab-1">
<span>This is working.</span></div>
<div id="tab-2">
<span>And so is this</span></div>
<div id="tab-3">NOT THIS</div>
<div id="tab-4">NOR THIS</div>

<!--product-template.liquid-Along with CSS--><div>
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab-1">Description</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2">Specs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-3">Shipping</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-4">Returns</a></li>
  </ul>
  {{ product.description }}
</div>

/*theme.js*/$(theme.init);

 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.tabs').each(function(){
      var active, content, links = $(this).find('a');
      active = links.first().addClass('active');
      content = $(active.attr('href'));
      links.not(':first').each(function () {
        $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
      });
      $(this).find('a').click(function(e){
        active.removeClass('active');
        content.hide();
        active = $(this);
        content = $($(this).attr('href'));
        active.addClass('active');
        content.show();
        return false;
      });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your tags. Rechecked mine and I think I misplaced a